# Where does the derivative of $\exp(q_2 c_k^x(x_k))$ go?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im reading a paper about CiLQR and have some questions. [http://people.iiis.tsinghua.edu.cn/~jychen/publication/2020pre/itsc2017jianyu/ITSC2017Jianyu.pdf](http://people.iiis.tsinghua.edu.cn/%7Ejychen/publication/2020pre/itsc2017jianyu/ITSC2017Jianyu.pdf)

[image]

One question is, how (11) leads to (12)? Where does the derivative of $\exp(q_2 c_k^x(x_k))$ go? Isnt this following $\nabla (fg)=\nabla f g + f\nabla g$?

PS: oh I handled it wrong, it should be, where did the second order derivative $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ go? Is it possible that because the second order derivative matrix is small so the author neglected it in (12)?